# Exporting Database From Oracle and Importing Into MariaDB

Tags: oracle, mariadb, database-migration

I am doing a data migration from oracle to mariadb. What are the best practices that are typically implemented for database migration. I know theres migration tools to help export from oracle and import into mariadb (ex HEVO) but Im not entirely convinced this will resolve all of my problems. For example oracle provides a native import/export tool called expdp/impdp to create a dump file but mariadb does not support reading the dump.

What are migration tools and best practices I should consider when migrating from Oracle to MariaDB?

Some notes:

- currently using oracle db
- mariadb donor has sql_mode=ORACLE enabled with datatyping issues (BigInt vs Long, and String Clob formatting which is detailed further below)
- current DB has ~20million rows
- can export dump file from oracle but mariadb does seem to recognize it
- can export 20k rows at a time using SQLDeveloper into csv but with 20M rows this isnt ideal and slow
- oracle db contains String CLOBs of XML string literals which break mariadb (CLOBS in mariadb require surrounding double quotes for every row, newline chars also break mariadb)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to your Oracle to MariaDB migration.

You can use MariaDB's Connect Engine to create a connection to the OracleDB.

There are many types, so a [JDBC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-jdbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) Connect engine type to the OracleDB is one way.

Follow the install instructions for connect engine in your configuration file:

```
plugin-load-add=ha_connect
```

You may also need to configure [connect_jvm_path](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-system-variables/#connect_jvm_path) and [connect_class_path](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-system-variables/#connect_class_path) to files containing JDBC connectors for Oracle.

Create a server to make the name `oracle` refer to the server:

```
create server 'oracle' foreign data wrapper 'oracle' options (
HOST 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe',
DATABASE 'SYSTEM',
USER 'system',
PASSWORD 'manager',
PORT 0,
SOCKET '',
OWNER 'SYSTEM');
```

Create the connect engine table to the OracleDB:

```
create table employees_oracle engine=connect table_type=JDBC connection='oracle/HR.EMPLOYEES';
```

Then create the identical MariaDB table:

```
create table employees like employees_oracle;
```

Check it has all the right indexes:

```
show create table employees;
```

Make the employees table a local MariaDB InnoDB table of the same structure:

```
alter table employees engine=InnoDB
```

and then:

```
insert into employees select * from employees_oracle;
```

Use `sql_mode=ORACLE` in the server and see if your existing applications work correctly with MariaDB.

Please report [any bugs](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: I will try this out. One followup question: Does MariaDB Connect Engine pipeline provide a way to validate the data post-migration?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. Connect Engine would need to be checking its own conversion. I guess you could do a `JOIN` between `employees_oracle` and `employees_oracle` for non-identical row data and assume it got the PK correct.